# Using python's with with os.fork

Tags: python, linux, fork

I'm currious as to know if the behavior of with with os.fork is defined somehow in the python specification and how I should use with with os.fork.

If I do, for example:

```
import tempfile
import os
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir:
  pid = os.fork()
  print(pid)
  print(dir)
```

Then it seems to be using the naive behavior of deleting the TemporaryDirectory twice:

```
> python3 foo.py
27023
/tmp/tmpg1typbde
0
/tmp/tmpg1typbde
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 824, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 828, in cleanup
    _rmtree(self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 467, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 465, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpg1typbde'
```

I'm wondering:

1. If the behavior is actually defined
2. How best should I share a temporary directory between two processes

Comment: Perhaps you could use ``os._exit()`` in the child process to terminate without any cleanup being done.  This assumes that everything that needs to be cleaned up is shared with the parent process.

Comment: Not a real answer, but is it really necessary do go on that level? Usually there are more tailored mechanisms to manage multiple processes in python for a specific job, e.g. multiprocessing.

Comment: @languitar I'm not sure. The code I'm working on right now is in my test suit. The goal of the code is to spawn many versions of my program to try to test if there are any race conitions in the locking code on program launch. So I really want things to be happening concurrently ;) . But you're probably right in general, that os.fork isn't the best thing to do in python...

Comment: I'd probably just give the program a command line argument to override the temp dir and then launch it multiple times via `subprocess`.

Comment: Its probably just supersitsion, but I feel like I'm more likely to trigger race conditions if I launch things from separate processes.

Comment: @timthelion but subprocess launches different processes?

Comment: But it doesn't return emediately, it actually waits for the new process to be start before returning. So it launches different processes, but if you want the process launching sequence (building the process tree objectects that are exposed in /proc/) to happen at the same time... I know, it is probably just superstition, but race conditions are hard to trigger...

Answer (score 1):

Not using with, and doing this the dirty old way works.

```
> cat foo.py
import tempfile
import os
import shutil
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="foo")
pid = os.fork()
print(pid)
print(temp_dir)
if not pid:
  input("pid: %s\nPress enter to continue."%pid)
if pid:
  print("pid: %s\nWaiting for other pid to exit."%pid)
  os.waitpid(pid,0)
  shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
  print("Bye")
```

.

```
> python3 foo.py
27510
/tmp/foopyvuuwjw
pid: 27510
Waiting for other pid to exit.
0
/tmp/foopyvuuwjw
pid: 0
Press enter to continue.
Bye
```